# Stored procedure not updating data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to pass a data table to a stored procedure. The table has four columns, `OldDifficulty`, `OldIndex`, `NewDifficulty`, and `NewIndex`. It is passed to a stored procedure which is supposed to update all the rows in a `Puzzles` table changing rows with the old index and difficulty to their new index and difficulty. The `Puzzles` table does not change, and I can't figure out why. I'm not sure whether the problem is in the code or in the database query.

Here is the C# code that calls the stored procedure:

```
  var Form = context.Request.Form;
  DataTable table = new DataTable();
  table.Columns.Add("OldDifficulty");
  table.Columns.Add("OldIndex");
  table.Columns.Add("NewDifficulty");
  table.Columns.Add("NewIndex");
  foreach (var key in Form.Keys)
  {
    var Old = key.ToString().Split('_');
    var New = Form[key.ToString()].Split('_');
    if (Old == New || New.Length == 1 || Old.Length == 1) continue;
    table.Rows.Add(Old[0], int.Parse(Old[1]), New[0], int.Parse(New[1]));
  }
  using (var con = new SqlConnection(SqlHelper.ConnectionString))
  {
    con.Open();
    using (var com = new SqlCommand("RearrangePuzzles", con))
    {
      com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ChangedPuzzles", table) 
        { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured });
      com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();
  }
```

and here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RearrangePuzzles]
    @ChangedPuzzles ChangedPuzzlesTable READONLY
AS
UPDATE p 
SET 
    NthPuzzle = cp.NewIndex, 
    Difficulty = cp.NewDifficulty 
FROM 
    Puzzles p JOIN 
    @ChangedPuzzles cp ON cp.OldIndex = p.NthPuzzle AND cp.OldDifficulty = p.Difficulty
```

Do you have any idea why the table isn't updating? Is there something wrong with my SQL?

Comment: what is your sqlserver version ?

Comment: com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ChangedPuzzles", table)=> 
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChangedPuzzles", table) - could be this as well, but it would be helpful to know the exact error before jumping into conclusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks ok, except:

```
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ChangedPuzzles", table) 
    { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured });
```

I would change to:

```
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChangedPuzzles", table) 
    { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured });
```

`@` sign - prefix in [parameter name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.parametername.aspx).

Use SQL Server Profiler to see whether this query actually is executed.

Answer (score 1):

check the order of fields in the table type ChangedPuzzlesTable , it must be same as datatable any change in order may cause this problem

check error by adding a try catch

```
  try
    {
     using (var con = new SqlConnection(SqlHelper.ConnectionString))
      {
        con.Open();
        using (var com = new SqlCommand("RearrangePuzzles", con))
        {
          com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ChangedPuzzles", table) 
            { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured });
          com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
      }
    }

catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   // ex will show you the error
                }
```